# IPhone Frame Video Playing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have written this piece of objective-c code for playing a video after touching an image.

```
    //start video here
    NSString *path = [self localVideoPath:NO];

    // Create custom movie player   
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithPath:path] autorelease];

    [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(onMSAASDone:)
        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
        object:moviePlayer];

    [moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:FALSE];

    //---play partial screen---
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300);
    //[[moviePlayer view] setFrame: [image bounds]];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

    // Show the movie player as modal
    //[self presentModalViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES];

    // Prep and play the movie
    [moviePlayer play];
```

The problem is that the code stops working at second line of statement. The error is... Program GDB: Received Signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Help Me Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithPath:path] autorelease];
```

the function `initWithPath` is not the part of `MPMoviePlayerController` class, 
i could not find it in documentation.
May be you were trying to use

```
- (id)initWithContentURL:(NSURL *)url
```

plz read the apple documentation.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Ok I tested it and it's fixed but the ultimate issue isn't resolved since then. I click the image and it goes off but the video player never comes in to play the video. Any help?

Comment: @Umair Ashraf :The above post is only related with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"..Correct Umair ..